# Exception while accessing calendar on android device

Tags: android, android-calendar

Getting an exception while launching Calendar on android device.

**Logcat:**

`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.calendar, PID: 7209
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
       at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:48)
       at com.android.calendar.calendarlist.CalendarListUtils.processCursor(CalendarListUtils.java:155)
       at com.android.calendar.calendarlist.SelectCalendarsAdapter.swapCursor(SelectCalendarsAdapter.java:160)
       at com.android.calendar.calendarlist.DrawerFragment.onLoadFinished(DrawerFragment.java:244)
       at com.android.calendar.calendarlist.DrawerFragment.onLoadFinished(DrawerFragment.java:55)
       at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
       at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
       at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:144)
       at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:109)
       at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:97)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:265)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:92)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Force finishing activity com.google.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.AllInOneCalendarActivity
```

`

[image]

Did anyone get this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about using a third-party application; Stack Overflow is intended for programming questions.

Comment: the user account you tired to use has empty name

Comment: From where should I set the user account? Other applications of Google on this phone are working fine. I was trying to install a cordova application which uses calendar. After installation of that application the calendar stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Krishna,

Problem could be solved by setting --> App and clearing cache and data from the calendar app and do a force stop of the calendar app.

Also, there is one more app which is running for calendar called "Calendar storage", which could be found in Setting --> App and on the top menu click on Show System.

On this screen all system Apps will be visible. Click on Calendar storage and follow all the steps for clearing cache and data and force stop the app.

Now start the Calendar App, It will start without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an off-topic question. StackOverflow is intended for programming questions. 
Anyway, just for the sake of answering, I think your Calendar app hasn't been **granted permissions sufficient permissions.**

Head over to Settings --> Apps --> Calendar.
Click on Permissions and enable all in it.

Now reboot the phone and try. It should work by now.

If it still doesn't work, try clearing it's data & cache and try again.

Comment: It is a programming related question itself. I was trying to install a cordova application which uses calendar. After installation of that application the calendar stopped working. Other applications of Google on this phone are working fine.